# Insert Into Big Table Performance Optimization In Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, query-performance, teradatasql

Daily ETL process is trying to load incremental data into Teradata Table containing Billions of rows.

Table is a SET table with Non Unique PI.

Direct Dump from Stage table to Target is taking high AMP CPU Time.

Changed the target table to Multi Set, still the AMP CPU Time is similar.

Insert into an Empty table is very cheap but insert into huge tables are big.

Is there any way to improve/reduce AMP Cpu?

Comment: Is the target table partitioned? How many rows are inserted?

Comment: No table is not partitioned. There is no date column to partition on. Or any set value column which has even distribution of data

Comment: Daily data load range from 50-150 M rows

Comment: This load is probably touching almost every datablock, what's your Teradata release? Is the table Block Level Compressed?

Comment: Teradata 16.20 Intelicloud. Yes it is block level compressed

Comment: I dont see BLC in the create statement

Comment: BLC is probably the default. Check `dbc.StatsV.BLCCompRatio` for `StatsId = 0`

Comment: Yes the BLCompRatio is 51.. Is there any way to reduce CPU Consumption